# Why's Auth::user() returning null even though I'm logging in successfully?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

I'm using Laravel Passport

I'm not sure why `dd(Auth::user());` is returning `null` even though I'm logging in successfully.  I see the auth token being returned which indicates that I've logged in but then why does the `dd(Auth::user());` say otherwise?

I've looked around for a possible solution but to no avail.

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    $credentials = ['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password];

    if (Auth::guard('web')->attempt($credentials, false)) {
        $token = auth('web')->user()->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
        dd(Auth::user());
        
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Successfully logged in',
            'loginToken' => $token
        ]);
    }

    return $this->sendError('Unauthorized.', ['error' => 'Unauthorized']);
}
```

Comment: If you default guard is not web - use `Auth::user('web')`

Comment: @Maksim `Auth::user('web')` won't work because the method signature takes no paramters.

Comment: Hmm.. pls try `Auth::guard('web')->user()`

Answer (score 0):

you need middleware for using Auth::user()

Comment: Yes, I'm using middleware.  But when I take the route out of the middleware, that's when I'm able to login successfully.  When the route is in the middleware, I'm unable to login and the network returns `unauthenticaed`.